# Is it possible to compile a single C++ translation unit in parallel?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, clang

Is it possible to compile a single C++ translation unit in parallel?

If so, how? (specifically how to do it with e.g. clang or gcc)

Otherwise, why not?

Comment: Compilers can be made highly concurrent, but true parallelism for single translation units would be quite a feat.

Comment: I wonder why would compiler vendors care to make it possible. There is usually a lot of translation units in projects to make good use of all available processors/cores.

Comment: Sounds at least pretty hard to implement. Probably you should split up your translation unit.

Comment: @JurajBlaho I sincerely don't know how hard it would be, but it might make sense e.g. for heavily templated code or code using lots of header only libraries. I just wondered if this might be possible (e.g. in gcc or clang), or if it is very hard, it would be enlightening for me to know the reason.

Comment: @gnzlbg for code using alot of (big) headers most compiler already provide a feature called precompiled header files.

Comment: @gnzlbg: Multithreading is always associated with some work and a risk of more bugs. And here it just does not seem to bring any benefit. Compiler vendors just have enough of more important work to do. It could even make things slower as there would be multiple compiler processes each with multiple threads = more threads than cores. There would also be some cost of synchronization and communication.

Comment: Much of that is being handled by precompiling header files. Also, translation units are essentially sequential, in that later parts of the file depend on earlier ones. So this is hard to do. More is to be gained by compiling files in parallel.

Comment: Sounds like you have too big files. Where I work we have some systems like that which we often make jokes about.

Comment: @Paranaix , vonbrand can you precompile header-only template libraries like boost? A lot of people complain that using boost significantly increases compile times. Does precompiling help there? (If the answer is yes I will ask how to precompile boost in a different question)

Comment: @vonbrand see my previous comment, couldn't tag you there.

Comment: @tgmath yes, splitting a translation unit allows you to compile it in parallel, i'm however interested in compiling a single TU in parallel.

Comment: @JurajBlaho makes sense, do you know of any quantitative evidence? (E.g. how much slower would the compiler be and so on).

Comment: Regardless of the answer, this is a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I very much doubt that it is possible to compile in parallel.

The C and C++ languages depend on the order of evaluation. A #define higher in the file might change the meaning of everything that follows it. In C++ an operator might call a function or do another operation, depending on the existence of an operator override function. In fact, the existence or non-existence of a symbol name might affect if it is interpreted as a variable or a type.

The simple parts of parsing that might be done in parallel without reference to symbol tables are so easy to do that threading them hardly makes sense. And the hard parts are inherently serialized.

A language might be designed to allow parallel compilation in a single unit, but it wouldn't be C.

Comment: The initial interpretation of the C++ source files has a lot of sequential dependencies, true.  (My company actually builds a C++ front end that determines partial orders over such dependencies and evaluates them in parallel for C++11, for program analysis/transformation purposes).  But once name and type resolution is complete, one ought to be able to compile the individual methods independently.

Answer (score 1):

Probably in theory, but pointless in practice.

The preprocessor thread can emit a sequence of tokens to be compiled, and the actual compilation thread can pick those up as they are produced. Similarly, the linker thread can be fed compiled functions as they are produced, because it can start before the last function is known.

Peephole optimization can also be done in parallel, pretty much by definition. But that needs to alternate with other optimization steps such as inlining, which is a bit harder to do in parallel.

But as the comments indicated, any real program has more translation units than you have cores. You'd waste time by having to synchronize two threads for a single TU.

Linking is of course an entirely different matter.